# Can one segue identifier be used between two UIViewControllers for multiple UITableView cell data transfer?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

I'd just like to confirm my understanding that for every segue identifier, there needs to be a unique segue hookup between two UIViewControllers in Interface Builder. Is this true?

Is it possible to have ONE hookup between 2 UIViewControllers in InterfaceBuilder with IF statements to change the identifier programmatically? If not, I'll be going crazy in segue city.

How many segues can be hooked up between 2 viewcontrollers? Infinite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you don't want to go crazy in segue city, don't use a storyboard. I've never liked them, and I don't think they provide any serious advantage.

But if you must use a storyboard, then each segue that has an identifier should have a *unique* identifier. You cannot change the identifier in code when the app is running. You can, however, *use* the identifier to *choose* a segue in real time in code. So if view controller A is connected to view controller B, and view controller A is also connected to view controller C, you can decide in code which segue to use, and specify it by identifier.